# Clean URL with mod_rewrite including sub directory inside domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use `mod-rewrite` in `.htaccess` for implementing clean/pretty URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- `RewriteEngine On` turns the engine on.
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` does not rewrite anything if the
  request filename exists, and is a file.
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` does not rewrite anything if the
  request filename exists, and is a directory.
- `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`  This is the actual
  rewrite rule.  It takes anything after the domain name (anything
  other than forward slashes),  and rewrites it to `details.php`, passing
  it as the `id` parameter.

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`  is working when request for **http://www.domain.com/texas**

This is well and good. **What I need is** that my request URL looks like this:
**http://www.domain.com/location/texas**

and `details.php` has the below code

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
echo "new id is ".$id;
?>
```

**Problem:** I couldn't write a valid `.htaccess` `RewriteRule` to identify this request `http://www.domain.com/location/texas`.
Please help.

*What all I tried?*

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteRule ^location/?$ details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`   - not working

`RewriteRule ^location/[a-z][-a-z0-9]*?$ details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]` - working, but `id` is displayed blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just tweak your existing rule by making starting `location/` optional:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:location/)?([^/]+)/?$ details.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you!, It's working!! Now let me understand your code. Gimme 2 mins, I'll accept

Comment: Instead of making `location` optional, how do I make it mandatory?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^location/([^/]+)/?$ details.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: cool, I was also trying. Thank you so much man. I've seen you around SO. Today got your direct help :)